# How to reset the radiobutton value from frontend and backend in LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript

Image for reference.
this is the correct way to show options.
[image: this is the correct way to show options.]

but I am getting the option already selected when I am going to next question.
[image]

when clicking on next button I am going to next question but the selected value is moving to next question also.

```
next question function to load new values
nextQuestion() {
        try {
            this.dispatchEvent(new RefreshEvent())
            this.callAPI();
            this.shuffleArrayAndSetupWAR();
            this.handleRadioChange();
            if((this.selectAns === this.correctanswer) && (this.selectAns !=null)){
                this.correctAnswerCounter++;
            }
            this.selectedAnswers.push(this.selectAns);
            this.publishMessage();
            this.resetRadio();  //trying to clear the selected value from here
            console.log(this.selectAns);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(this.selectedAnswers));
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.error('Error11', err.message);
        }
    }


resetRadio(){
        this.template.querySelector('itemSelection').checked = 'false';
    }
```

but the values are not getting reset.
Can somebody help me acheive the thing I am trying to do.
Let me know if some more information is needed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript can be tricky sometimes. Here, `'false'` is actually a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value. Aside from that, each radio box is its own element, so you need to query them all. That comes with another trick: `querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList`, which ironically is not a list (formally, an Array), so we have to convert it if we want to use it as such. We can do that with the following syntax: `[...someVariable]`. This will unlock the ability to use `forEach` and other `Array` functions. Third, `'itemSelection'` is going to try to find an element that is called `itemSelection`, which doesn't exist. I'm going to hazard a guess that you named the radio inputs like that, so you need to use `'input[name="itemSelection"]'` instead.

So, the final solution looks like this:

```
[...this.template.querySelectorAll('input[name="itemSelection"]')].forEach(
  (input) => { input.checked = false; }
);
```

Comment: <label><input type="radio" name="itemSelection" value={answer.name} onclick={handleRadioChange} />{answer.name}</label>
this is the radio button. Should I also add the checked=true attribute in this?

Comment: @HadiHusain There should be no need for that. I did have a typo in my code, though. I meant to say `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: sadly this is also not working. var tmparr = Array.from(this.template.querySelectorAll('input[name="itemSelection"]'));
            tmparr.forEach((input) => {input.checked = false}) 
I am passing like this in function.

Answer (score 0):

this.dispatchEvent(new RefreshEvent()) will work no need for resetting the buttons.

Comment: So how does `this.dispatchEvent(new RefreshEvent())` prevent the next option to appear already checked, without the need to reset the buttons?

Comment: its not resetting the buttons, I am refreshing them now. I came to this conclusion that when the component is loaded first time the values are not checked so that means I have to juat refresh the component. Hope this clears the doubt.